# List quickly all settings of your Django project

Tags: python, django

Probably this will not be difficult question for python experts, so please help. I want to quickly list all settings of my django project. I want to have a simple python script for that (in a separate file). Here is how I started:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()
settings_list = dir(settings)

for i in settings_list:
    settings_name = i
    print settings_name
```

In this way I get names of all settings. However after each `settings_name` I want to print its value. Tried many ways. Looks like those settings are actually empty. For example:

```
print settings.INSTALLED_APPS
```

returns empty list. I execute the script from django root directory and inside project's virtual environment.

Please suggest the right method to print out all settings for my Django project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems which has to be answered: 1) settings are empty 2) how to iterate over attributes and values in **settings** object.

Regarding **empty settings** - referencing to [django documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/)

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
print settings.SECRET_KEY
```

should work, BUT for some reason it didn't in my case. So instead below code worked for me:

```
from django.conf import settings
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_django_project.settings'
print settings.SECRET_KEY
```

Then in order to collect attributes and values from **settings** object, I used below code, which I actually borrowed from [django-print-settings](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-print-settings/):

```
a_dict = {}

for attr in dir(settings):
    value = getattr(settings, attr)
    a_dict[attr] = value

for key, value in a_dict.items():
            print('%s = %r' % (key, value))
```

To summarize, my full code in my *print_settings.py* file now looks:

```
from django.conf import settings
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_django_project.settings'

a_dict = {}

for attr in dir(settings):
    value = getattr(settings, attr)
    a_dict[attr] = value

for key, value in a_dict.items():
            print('%s = %r' % (key, value))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call Django's built-in [diffsettings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#diffsettings):

```
from django.core.management.commands import diffsettings

output = diffsettings.Command().handle(default=None, output="hash", all=False)

desensitized = []
for line in output.splitlines():
    if "SECRET" in line or "KEY" in line:
        continue
    desensitized.append(line)
print("\n".join(desensitized))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer I am expecting, but I found another good solution how to print all settings of Django project.

This can be done by installing python package **django-print-settings**:

```
pip install django-print-settings
```

I found it from here https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-print-settings/. Please refer to that site for setup and usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
import django, os
from django.conf import settings
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings' # Settings will pick this up on lazy init.
for attr in dir(settings):
  print "%-40s: %s" % (attr, getattr(settings, attr))
```